# Will Erlang R17 still have records?

Tags: erlang

According to [Joe Armstrong](http://joearms.github.io/2014/02/01/big-changes-to-erlang.html):

> Records are dead - long live maps !

But according to the [EEP for maps](https://github.com/psyeugenic/eep/blob/egil/maps/eeps/eep-0043.md):

> Maps were not envisioned as a record replacement at first, it was a hopeful requirement added later.

From these conflicting messages, it is unclear to me whether records will still be in R17, or whether they will be deprecated and removed in a future version. Can anyone add some insight?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way they would throw records anytime soon.. There is too much code depending on them.. see http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_17.0-rc1.readme (especially OTP-10652)

Comment: They also target different types of usage. You could use maps as a replacement for records but there are some things you will lose if you do. I more see maps as a replacement for property lists which will have the added effect of making that type of data structure both easier to use and more useful.

Comment: Agreed... the closest thing Erlang has to a statically defined data structure is records. It didn't seem like maps could ever replace that. Which is why the claim "records are dead" was startling.

Comment: I think it more overenthusiastic than anything else. We have been waiting for this, or something like it, for quite a while.

Comment: i love the records. it will hurt when they are gone. They are a remarkable data structure